# How can I store the data inputted to the form? ReactJS / Prisma

Tags: reactjs, database, prisma

I recently started studying ReactJS and Prisma and I am trying to store the data collected via form to the database. But I can't seem to understand what I would do to connect each other. I've read the Prisma CRUD docs and followed it but I get an error. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTvDN.png)

This is the code that I tried to use:

```
const EmployeeTable = async () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState([] as any);

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [employeeID, setEmployeeID] = useState("");

    const Employee = await prisma.employee.create({
      data: {
        name: name,
        employeeID: employeeID,
      },
    });
    
    const handleSubmit = (event:any) => {
      event.preventDefault();
        setFormData([...formData, Employee]);
        setName("");
        setEmployeeID("");
    };
```

```
// schema.prisma
model Employee {
    id         String   @id @default(cuid())
    name       String?
    employeeID String?  @unique
    state      Boolean  @default(false)
    createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt  DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

What I wanted was to store the data inputted in the form to the database.